# I am building a website and would like to add a 'bookmark this page' button which will be compatible with iOS

Tags: html, ipad, web, icons, bookmarks

I am building a website and would like to add a 'bookmark this page' button which will be compatible with iOS

The client would like to be able to have people tap the 'bookmark' button and automatically ad an icon to the iPad desktop-thing (create a bookmark). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You should inform visitors of the possibility to make a web clip (icon on the home screen), but you can't do it for them.

[image: Mobile bookmark bubble]

You can use a [mobile bookmark bubble](http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/) to trigger users to add a web clip to there home screen.